# Reordering a query to group all authors together and in descending order according to published date

Tags: django

I am building a forum where one person posts a message and several other people respond to it.

I have a message model and a response model as follows:

```
class Messages (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message

class Responses (models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Messages)
    responder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='responder')
    rsp_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rsp_to')
    rsp_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rsp_from')
    response = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

I would like to obtain a queryset that is organized according to responder so that all the responses from the latest responder are first, the responses from the second latest responder are second, and so on.

Example db table:

```
pk  message  responder  rsp_to  rsp_from  response  pub_date
------------------------------------------------------------
1    a        User.2  a.author   User.2    ....      1
2    a        User.3  a.author   User.3    ....      2
3    a        User.3  User.3    a.author   ....      3
4    a        User.4  a.author   User.4    ....      4
5    a        User.4  User.4    a.author   ....      5
6    a        User.2  User.2    a.author   ....      6
7    a        User.3  a.author   User.3    ....      7
8    a        User.3  User.3    a.author   ....      8
9    a        User.4  a.author   User.4    ....      9
```

Reordered queryset:

```
pk  message  responder  rsp_to  rsp_from  response  pub_date
------------------------------------------------------------
9    a        User.4  a.author   User.4    ....      9
5    a        User.4   User.4   a.author   ....      5
4    a        User.4  a.author   User.4    ....      4
8    a        User.3   User.3   a.author   ....      8
7    a        User.3  a.author   User.3    ....      7
3    a        User.3   User.3   a.author   ....      3
2    a        User.3  a.author   User.3    ....      2
6    a        User.2   User.2   a.author   ....      6
1    a        User.2  a.author   User.2    ....      1
```

Alternatively expressed as:

```
r = [<all responses from latest responder>, <all responses from 2nd latest responder>,..., <all responses from earliest responder>]
```

If I start with:

```
r = Responses.objects.filter(message="a").order_by('-pub_date')
```

I get the latest response first.  How can I reorder the queryset so that all the responses from that latest unique responser are grouped first in the queryset, all the responses from the second,unique responder are grouped second, and so on?

Comment: How about adding second order by clause? r = Responses.objects.filter(message="a").order_by('-pub_date', 'responder ')

Comment: or r = Responses.objects.filter(message="a").order_by('-pub_date', 'responder__id')

Comment: It is a convention to name the models in singular, in your case 'Message' and 'Response'.

Answer (score 0):

### Using sorted()

Let's first consider doing the sorting in Python using the good old [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) function. It is a type of [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), i.e. it does the sorting by comparing items in pairs, one pair at a time, and for each pair deciding which one should come first. Comparison sort only works when the comparator (the function given as an argument to sort) defines a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order):

1. If a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b (antisymmetry, in fact not necessary for comparison sort);
2. If a ≤ b and b ≤ c then a ≤ c (transitivity);
3. a ≤ b or b ≤ a (totality).

So if you can define a comparator, that takes two rows from your table and decides which one goes first, and that comparator defines a total order, then you can just call `sorted` with that comparator.

But such a comparator simply does not exist for your problem. When considering only two rows by two different users, you never know which one should come first. You will always need to know the most recent post by those authors. Bottom line: You can't use `sorted()`

### Using SQL

I don't know if SQL can handle this. Try and rewrite your question leaving out all the Django and Python stuff, only with the tables you have. If you create such a question, please add a link from this question to that one. If SQL can handle it, then you can call `Responses.objects.sql()`.

### Using buckets

The code below is an example of how to sort the way you want, using buckets. I have used a dummy class Response, to focus on the principles.

```
from random import randint, shuffle

# == Data definition ==
class Response:
  user = None #int
  time = None #int
  def __str__(self):
    return '(%d:%2d)' % (self.user,self.time)

# == Create random data ==
responses = []
for i in range(20):
  r = Response()
  r.user = randint(1,4)
  r.time = i
  responses.append(r)
shuffle(responses)

# == Put in buckets ==
bucketdict = {}
for r in responses:
  if r.user in bucketdict:
    bucketdict[r.user].append(r)
  else:
    bucketdict[r.user] = [r]

# == create list from dict ==
bucketlist = bucketdict.items()
def printbucketlist():
  for user,user_rsps in bucketlist:
    print user, 
    for rsp in user_rsps:
      print rsp,
    print
  print
printbucketlist()

# == Sort responses within each bucket ==
def rsp_comparator(r1,r2):
  return r2.time - r1.time
for user,responses in  bucketlist:
  responses.sort(rsp_comparator)
printbucketlist()

# == Sort bucketlist ==
def bucket_cmp(b1,b2):
  # assumes that the first response in the list has the highet time
  return b2[1][0].time - b1[1][0].time
bucketlist = sorted(bucketlist,cmp=bucket_cmp)
printbucketlist()

# == Concatenate into one list ==
sortedresponses = []
for user, user_rsps in bucketlist:
  for response in user_rsps:
    sortedresponses.append(response)
for response in sortedresponses:
  print response
```